# Removing inline elements when importing HTML into DOMDocument or SimpleXML?

Tags: php, html, parsing, simplexml, domdocument

I have an external HTML source that I want to scrape and either transform into a local XML file or add to a MySQL DB.

The external source is mostly normalized and (somewhat) semantic, so that all I need to do is use `XPATH` to get all `td` content or all `li` content, etc. The problem is that occasionally these items use `<strong>` or `<b>` or `<i>` tags to style the elements I need.

This is technically semantic, since the point is to add emphasis to the specific text, and the developer might want to use CSS that isn't the browser default.

The problem is that the actual content I am trying to grab is considered a child of this inline element, so that PHP extensions like `simplexml` or `DOMDocument` and `DOMNode` treat them as such. For example:

```
<table>
<tr><td>Thing 1</td><td>Thing 2</td></tr>
<tr><td>Thing 3</td><td>Thing 4</td></tr>
<tr><td><strong>Thing 5</strong></td><td><strong>Thing 6</strong></td></tr>
</table>
```

Will result in:

```
 [table] =>
    [tr] =>
        [td] => Thing 1
        [td] => Thing 2
    [tr] =>
        [td] => Thing 3
        [td] => Thing 4
    [tr] =>
        [td] => 
            [strong] => Thing 5
        [td] => 
            [strong] => Thing 6
```

Obviously the above is not quite what simplexml returns, but the above reflects the general problem.

So is there a way, using either a parameter already built into DOMDocument or using an extra sophisticated XPath query to get the contents of the `td` element with any children (if there are any) stripped of their descendant status and all content treated as the text of the queried element?

Right now, the only solutions I have are to either:

a) have a `foreach` loop that checks each result, like:

```
$result_text = ($result -> strong) ? $result - strong : $result;
```

b) using regex to strip any `<strong>` tags out of the HTML string before importing it into any pre-built classes like simplexml or DOMDocument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just use [strip_tags()](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) to remove the extra markup?

```
$table = simplexml_load_string(
    '<table>
        <tr><td>Thing 1</td><td>Thing 2</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Thing 3</td><td>Thing 4</td></tr>
        <tr><td><strong>Thing 5</strong></td><td><strong>Thing 6</strong></td></tr>
    </table>'
);

foreach ($table->xpath('//td') as $td)
{
    $content = strip_tags($td->asXML());
    echo $content, "\n";
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the BEST solution, but I'm accepting it based not so much on the `strip_tags` suggestion (which is clever), but on the asXML() suggestion, which didn't occur to me to use BEFORE dealing with moving the contents to an array. Very nice.

Answer (score 1):

Please read the first answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) before parsing html with a regex, if only for amusement sake. XPath is the answer, get the text of the td instead of continuing to parse it. So you'll just search for something like `//td` and take the results of that completely (instead of continuing the tree building so that you have leaves that say strong or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using DOMDocument, once you've selected a DOMNode, the property `textContent` should  contain only the text part of it and all it's childen... *exactly* what you asked for.

```
$table = '<table>
        <tr><td>Thing 1</td><td>Thing 2</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Thing 3</td><td>Thing 4</td></tr>
        <tr><td><strong>Thing 5</strong></td><td><strong>Thing 6</strong></td></tr>
    </table>';

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($table);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$els = $xpath->query('//td');
echo $els->item(4)->textContent; //Thing 5
```

Alternatively, depending on the type of node, you can check `nodeValue` as well. I can't recall exactly the difference, but [textContent](http://us.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php#domnode.props.textcontent) is what you want.